# Why does the X Y Z translations now rotate along with my static meshes?

Tags: unreal, map-editor

So I was making a map for UT3, using the Unreal 3 Editor provided, and all was going well.

However I was doing some work with InterpActors and Vehicle Spawners, when I must have hit a key by mistake (or other wise somehow changed something) by mistake.

Now the X Y Z translations that are used to move objects around in the editor will rotate along with the object (Ive put images down below to help show what I mean)

This is very annoying because it also changes the direction the arrow keys move a rotated object, in the example below, the Down arrow key will now move the object to the right.

How can I fix this?

(Note both images are taken from the same viewpoint)

Before Rotation:

[image: Before Rotation]

After Rotation:

[image: After Rotation]

P.S. If someone could please provide me with the correct / better name for the X Y Z "things" it would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you're referring to is known as the "gizmo".  The reason it's facing the direction of the gizmo is because it's in local space and not world space.

To change it just click on the drop down box (location shown in image) and click World

[image: Location of how to change]

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks - The "World" and "Local" is a drop down box next to the widget toolbar. It was also in a tutorial I looked at, which simply said to make sure it was always on World, and not Local. Thanks, I set it to world and its working great now